# Dialogflow Training Conversation

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have some issues from my Agent. It often happens that what the “user says” fall into the wrong intent. So I am trying to training the agent by the specific section “TRAINING” (please see the screenshot). I am changing the wrong intent to fix the issue and when I click on the APPROVE button then nothing happens! The problem is that training does not start (the wheel gear does not turn). And the wrong intent returns again. So the Agent continues to choose wrong intent in some cases. I would know why this training section not is working …

[image: training-section-screenshot]

Comment: have you tried to recreate the intent, deleting and creating again with the correct phrases and actions ?

Comment: Hi @ewertonvsilva, I have fixed it by going back with a previous agent backup (August 2021). But the strange thing is this: the backup is equal to the “wrong agent”, the only thing that change is 3 months of the training by users. Going back in the past eliminated this 3 months of training:  it is as if the users had answered the wrong way and the agent understood that this is the right way to answer. I know that the agent does not train himself but my question is: can a wrong statement by users (repeated several times) cause wrong training?

Comment: yes, if the wrong answer were accept as correct for an intent, it may result in working training and wrongs results.